# What is causing this impossibly long return time in AC Brotherhood on the PS3?

Tags: ps3, assassins-creed-brotherhood

I just sent the assassin recruits on a normal quest, but now, it shows this impossibly large number (ending in `e+17`) for all of my twelve recruits:

[image: screenshot showing extremely large number for recruit Ortensia Orlandi]

Is this a known bug? And if so, can I fix this?

I don't fancy waiting several billion years for this to finish...

Guess I can't use any assassin signals going forward - or restarting the whole game.

Comment: Wow - is your PS3's clock set correctly? I don't know if it uses that somehow for this or not.  Asides from that, thats certainly a bug... but I can't find anything else about it on the internet

Comment: @TimmyJim I'm not sure it's set correctly, and I've moved it recently. However, I've run hundreds of quests and never had that problem after moving, this appeared after making them all full-blown assassins. Also, my PS3 isn't connected to the network.

Comment: @TimmyJim talk about egg on my face. I turned my console clock an hour back and everything is fine.

Comment: That would probably make a nice entry for the current "Screenshot of the Week #109".

Comment: Here's a curiousity: the value seems suspiciously close to 0x444444444444444.

Answer (score 20):

Okay so it turns out that my console clock apparently decided to jump an hour forward, which must've caused an under- or overflow in the game.

At least turning the clock back an hour seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: have you adjusted your clock recently for daylight savings?

Comment: @KellyThomas No, I didn't change anything, which is the weird part. I did move it recently, and the only explanation I can find is that it connected to the open WiFi nearby and got the time from the network (despite me having network time disabled???)

Comment: this is why developers shoould use UTC instead of local time for timing things...

Comment: 3e17 minutes is about 2^64 seconds. So I think you're right.

Comment: @Jason's spot on with the 2^64 seconds. Spot on answer. Internally the counter uses a 64-bit unsigned integer (max 1.8446744e+19). The variable stores the remaining seconds, divided it by 60 for the UI (max 3.0744573e+17). The fact that it's _unsigned_ means that it's caused it to "wrap" below its minimum value in your case when the result was negative due to a time data fault. It is absolutely a _type_ of underflow - an integer wraparound. 0/10 for data validation, devs - it is a bug. Can you accept your own answer as the solution?

Comment: @Rab: Actually, it's a type of overflow. Underflow is about loss of precision, which doesn't happen with integers.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Actually, "integer underflow" is a perfectly good way of describing this. The words "overflow" and "underflow" do not have a precise meaning within CS. For example, the C11 spec says “A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow” – clearly using a different definition to both you and Rab!

Comment: @Rab In other SE's I answered my own questions you need to wait two days after posting an answer to your own question before you can accept it. Probably the same here.

Comment: Moving clocks will mess with timers, this is exactly the kind of shenanigans you can expect as the result.